# react jest.mock doesn't mock files and fails all test using it

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm having issue testing with Jest. I made a react app with `create-react-app` and made some test. Right now, all of my test that use mocked data fails. Seems like `jest.mock('../../../main/services/api');`
 doesn't mock anything, as you can see with the error bellow

```
TypeError: _ScheduleAPI2.default.addAvailability is not a function

      at src/schedule/actions/scheduleActions.js:173:7183
      at Object.dispatch (node_modules/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:11:18)
      at Object.it (src/schedule/actions/__tests__/scheduleActions-test.js:361:18)
      at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:64:5)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Test example:

```
import ScheduleAPI from '../../services/ScheduleAPI';

jest.mock('../../services/ScheduleAPI');


.
.
.


  it('creates LOAD_MORE_APPROVED_APPOINTMENTS_FAILURE when loading more approved appointments fails', () => {
    ScheduleAPI.fetchApprovedAppointments.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw { status: 401, error: { error: 'unauthorized' } };
    });

    return store.dispatch(actions.loadMoreApprovedAppointments(A_DATE))
                .catch(() => {
                  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
                    { type: LOAD_MORE_APPROVED_APPOINTMENTS_REQUEST },
                    { type: LOAD_MORE_APPROVED_APPOINTMENTS_FAILURE },
                  ]);
                });
  });
```

The strangest thing in all is that this test pass in the project CI and for a coworker. Anyone would know why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly `throw new Error()` for an error, otherwise whatever you `throw` is going to `.then()` and not `.catch()`. Also the parameter for `throw new Error('unauthorized')` is a string that serves as a description of the error, you can't send a status or response object.